# Generalised newtype deriving on class functions with Functors

Tags: haskell

I'm developing a class representing key/value mappings, and I've got a function which is basically like [`alterF`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:alterF):

```
class C t where
  ...
  alterF :: Functor f => 
    (Maybe (Value t) -> f (Maybe (Value t))) -> Key t -> t -> f t
```

Unfortunately, this breaks [`GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes). In some cases, this is reasonable, as `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving` from what I understand essentially uses [Coercible](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) and the function [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce). `Coercible` represents types which are representationally equal, i.e. they have the same representation at run time, so we can convert between them for free. For example, given:

```
newtype T a = T a
```

we have:

```
Coercible a (T a)
Coercible (T a) a
```

but we don't have (in general):

```
Coercible (f a) (f (T a))
Coercible (f (T a)) (f a)
```

For example, GADTs violate this representational equality. But there are lots of values of `f` that do work. For example:

```
Coercible (Maybe a) (Maybe (T a))
Coercible (Maybe (T a)) (Maybe a)
Coercible [a] [T a]
Coercible [T a] [a]
Coercible (Identity a) (Identity (T a))
Coercible (Identity (T a)) (Identity a)
```

It also occurs to me that this instance could be written:

```
Functor f => Coercible (f a) (f (T a))
Functor f => Coercible (f (T a)) (f a)
```

Just using `fmap`. Unlike the usual `coerce`, this wouldn't be free at runtime, but it will work.

So I've got a class with 10 functions, 9 of which work fine with `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving`. There's just this final one which doesn't, which could be resolved mechanically using `fmap`. Do I have to write custom wrapping/unwrapping implementations for all my class functions, or is there a way to either require me to write the implementation for just the problem function or alternatively coax GHC into using `fmap` as part of it's `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving`?

Comment: Could you share a link with your development results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `f` is a `Functor`, you can make a "representational wrapper" for it

```
data Rep f a where
    Rep :: (b -> a) -> f b -> Rep f a
```

which is isomorphic to `f` except that it is representational in `a`, by what is essentially existential quantification over any nominal variance `f` might have.  I think this construction happens to have some fancy category theory name but I don't remember what it is.  To get the `f a` back out of a `Rep f a`, you need to use `f`'s `Functor`hood.

You can use this wrapper in your method, ensuring that your class varies representationally.

```
alterFRep :: (Functor f) 
          => (Maybe (Value t) -> Rep f (Maybe (Value t))) -> Key t -> t -> Rep f t
```

And then make the real "method" just a regular function in terms of it by using the isomorphism with `Rep f`.  You can also make a convenience method for instance authors:

```
toAlterFRep :: 
    (forall f t. (Functor f) => (Maybe (Value t) -> f (Maybe (Value t))) -> Key t -> t -> f t)
 -> (forall f t. (Functor f) => (Maybe (Value t) -> Rep f (Maybe (Value t))) -> Key t -> t -> Rep f t)
```

so they don't have to worry about what the heck `Rep` is, they just implement `alterF` normally and use `toAlterFRep` on it.

Comment: That's [`Coyoneda f a`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.5/kan-extensions-5.0.2/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html). This is a very impressive trick to change the type role (for functors). I would have thought that this was impossible.