# Writing a rewrite rule involving rank-n types

Tags: haskell, ghc

Below is a simplified version of a very similar problem I'm facing.

Consider the following types, and the function `f1`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype D t = D t deriving Functor
newtype T t = T { getT :: t }

f1 :: (forall t'. t' -> D t') -> T t -> D (T t)
```

Notice that `f1` can actually be `id`, because if we get passed function that works for all `t` we can of course specialise it like so:

```
f1 = id
```

Now lets consider the "inverse" function, `f2`:

```
f2 :: (T t -> D (T t)) -> t -> D t
```

This "unspecialises" the function, which can be implemented as follows:

```
f2 f x = getT <$> (f (T x))
```

We can combine `f2` and `f1` as follows, which is basically an identity function:

```
g :: (forall t'. t' -> D t') -> t -> D t
g x = f2 (f1 x)
```

Indeed, `g` is pretty much equivalent to the `id` function, and indeed we can instead define `g` as follows:

```
g = id
```

So we've established as `f2 . f1 == id`.

But when we write `f2 . f1`, I suspect GHC may not compile that down to `id`, because, `f2` at least does some non trivial work.

I'd like to write a rewrite rule for `f2 . f1`, and here's my attempt:

```
{-# RULES
"f2f1" forall x. f2 (f1 x) = g x
#-}
```

As `g` as can be defined as `id` I figured this might be good.

But unfortunately this fails to compile. I suspect this is due to the higher ranked type in `f1`.

I realise if I changed the type signature of `f1` like follows:

```
f1 :: (t -> D t) -> T t -> D (T t)
f1 f x = T <$> f (getT x)
```

I could write a rewrite rule like follows:

```
{-# RULES
"f2f1" forall x. f2 (f1 x) = x
#-}
```

But now whenever I use `f1` it isn't just `id`, but quite a bit more complex.

Is there a way to write a rewrite rule like `f2 . f1 == id`, without giving `f1` an non `id` style implementation?

**Further information:**

Note that in my actual problem, both `D` and `T` are not newtypes.

`D` is any `Functor f`, and `T` is actually a [`Coyoneda`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.1/docs/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html#t:Coyoneda), following on from [this previous question regarding newtype deriving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848571/generalised-newtype-deriving-on-class-functions-with-functors).

Comment: In your actual problem, do you know what `D` is? Because if it's really something polymorphic, you're going to struggle mightily to make a rewrite rule work on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polymorphic free variables in `RULES` must have type signatures. Simply use

```
{-# RULES
"f2/f1" forall (x :: forall t. t -> D t). f2 (f1 x) = x
  #-}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTNW got the answer written faster than I could. But let me address your underlying concern. If I define

```
g :: (forall t'. t' -> D t') -> t -> D t
g x = f2 (f1 x)
```

and compile with `-O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-coercions -dsuppress-idinfo`, I get

```
Clinton.g1
  :: forall t_aGp.
     (forall t'_aqH. t'_aqH -> D t'_aqH) -> t_aGp -> D (T t_aGp)
Clinton.g1 =
  \ (@ t_aGp)
    (x_aqY :: forall t'_aqH. t'_aqH -> D t'_aqH)
    (x1_Xrz :: t_aGp) ->
    x_aqY @ (T t_aGp) (x1_Xrz `cast` ...)

-- RHS size: {terms: 1, types: 0, coercions: 16}
g :: forall t_aqG.
     (forall t'_aqH. t'_aqH -> D t'_aqH) -> t_aqG -> D t_aqG
g = Clinton.g1 `cast` ...
```

Ignoring the type arguments and casts, which go away in code generation, this basically says

```
g f y = f y
```

which is pretty darn good. With your rewrite rule, we get

```
g :: forall t_aqG.
     (forall t'_aqH. t'_aqH -> D t'_aqH) -> t_aqG -> D t_aqG
g =
  \ (@ t_aGr) (x_aqY :: forall t'_aqH. t'_aqH -> D t'_aqH) ->
    x_aqY @ t_aGr
```

which is basically

```
g f = f
```

Better? Well, sort of. They're actually slightly *different*. Without the rewrite rule,

```
g undefined `seq` () = ()
```

With the rule,

```
g undefined `seq` () = undefined
```

Personally, I don't like to use rewrite rules that change semantics *at all*, and most especially ones that can reduce definedness, so I'd never write that one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dfuser. Perhaps my simplifications have hidden something here, which is my fault, and I've now noted this in my answer. Not that my code never actually defines `g`, just `f1` and `f2`, defining `g` was just for illustrative purposes to show `f1 . f2 == id`.

Comment: @Clinton, perhaps, but I think you'll likely still find it hard to be entirely correct, *especially* if you trust other people's `Functor` instances. Can you maybe ask about your actual problem? That could be more interesting to look at.

Comment: I think I'll finish the library as is, using what @HTNW has suggested, whack it up on github and drop a link here to the actual code.